# jsTree Check if New Name Exists on Rename

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am trying to allow a user to link samples with the locations they came from using jsTree. The user can drag samples and place them in the correct location. The locations are root nodes while the samples are child nodes. The user can also create new locations and then rename any locations that weren't already there. This all works so far.

I want to do a check on the rename event to ensure that the new name is unique. It can be the same as one of the samples, just not as another location node. I tried to use the search function, but it seems that all this does is fires off another event that you have to bind a function to instead of returning nodes/ids of found nodes.

How do I check if a root node exists with the new_name on the rename event and then cancel the rename if it does?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "It can be the same as one of the samples, just not as another location node."?? Please elaborate! I think I have the solution. But I need to know what u really want

Comment: Locations names have to be unique, and sample names have to be unique within the location, but it is acceptable if the sample has the same name as the location its attached to.

Comment: Oh I got it!! I will try with the code and get back to you!